# jQuery ajax call not working in ff and safari, but working in chrome, ie, ff on win

Tags: jquery, ajax, modx, modernizr

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
        $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a#deletefromcart").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var did = jQuery(this).data('delid');
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "assets/components/cart/deletefromcart.php",
                        cache:        false,
            data: "xid=" + did,
        });
        jQuery("tr.hide"+did).hide("slow");
        location.reload(true);
    });
```

Comment: Why `var $ = jQuery.noConflict()` ? Also, did you forget to post the closing `})` ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to wrap the `location.reload(true)` in the success callback of your AJAX request. Otherwise it may be reloading before the request has finished.

Also, the last item in a list for an object literal should not have a trailing comma (`,`). IE doesn't like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code. You have a trailing comma in your AJAX param list which will error in different browsers.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "assets/components/cart/deletefromcart.php",
  cache: false,
  data: "xid=" + did, // <------ RIGHT HERE
});
```